Visual Studio project fails when using Wix
I have a project that was developed many years ago using Visual Studio 2011 and embedding Installshield to compile distributable copies.  I need to enhance it so I have opened it in Visual Studio 2022.  I can run it in debug mode so I'm happy that it works, but I can't create a distributable copy because Installshield is now obsolete.
I think I should be able to use Wix as an alternative to Installshield so I have added the Heatwave extension to VS2022.  I made a copy of the project and opened it in the modified VS2022.  However, when I try to compile the programme I get errors:
Screenshot from VS2022 (https://i.sstatic.net/iAcdbej8.jpg)
Until I can resolve this I can't make any progress on achieving my aim.
Any suggestions why it works with VS2022 but not with VS2022+Heatwave?
The original project still works on another laptop running VS2022.  I made a copy of that project and ran it on VS2022+Heatwave and it generates compiler errors

There isn't enough information provided to suggest that this is a HearWave problem. Just adding the VS extension alone shouldn't cause issues. You'll need to dig deeper into your projects that are failing and provide more information to really diagnose anything.

I eventually solved the problems by adding "legacy_stdio_definitions.lib" to Linker>>General>>Adtional Library Directories (access by right-clicking the project in Solutions Explorer then clicking Properties), and disabling "Image has safe exception handlers" in Linker>>Advanced.
However,  the project now compiles correctly in Debug mode, but in Release mode it generates this error: "MSB3073 The command "S:\Dropbox\Ducx VS2010Wix\DUCX 1.0.27\Release\svnrev.exe". I can't find any reference to this error message, but it's in Microsoft.CppCommon.targets which is related to the Wix compiler

Microsoft.CppCommon.targets is part of .vcxproj and the C++ compiler from Visual Studio, not WiX.
